# Database connection script crashes after 4 successful connections

Tags: database, perl, dbi

I need to query a group of SAP sybase databases for some information and print that as a comma spearated list. So I figure I write a perl script that connects to any of those databases via DBI module. Here is what I came up with.

```
my $user = "someuser";
my $passwd = "somepassword";
my @sids=(filled with DB identifiers);
my $output="";
my $size;
my $version;
my $id;
my $dsn;
my $dbh;
my $sid;
my @row;
my $sth1;
my $sth2;
foreach $sid (@sids) {
        print $sid."\n";
        $dsn = "dbi:Sybase:server=$sid;charset=iso_1;tdsLevel=CS_TDS_50";
        print $dsn."\n";
        $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd,{ PrintError => 0,RaiseError => 0, AutoCommit => 1, syb_enable_utf8 => 1});
        print "DBI OK\n" if defined ($dbh);
        $sth1 = $dbh->prepare('select SUM(size) from master..sysusages WHERE dbid = 4 AND segmap = 3');
        $sth2 = $dbh->prepare('select @@version');
        $sth1->execute;
        while (@row = $sth1->fetchrow) {
                $size = $row[0];
        }
        $size = $size * 16 / 1024;
        $sth1->finish;
        $sth2->execute;
        while (@row = $sth2->fetchrow) {
                $version = $row[0];
        }
        $sth2->finish;
        $output = $sid.",".$size.",".$version;
        $dbh->disconnect;
        print $output."\n";
}
```

When I execute this, it crashes after 4th iteration, because the connection handle is not set. So the connection of the fifth DB does not work anymore.

```
Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at ./check_sybasedbs.pl line 36.
```

Line 36 is the preparation of statement 1.

I tried putting sleep commands at various positions. I also tried to explicitly clean up the variables that are reused via `undef`. Now I am out of ideas and would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Change `PrintError` and `RaiseError` to `1` when connecting to the databases and print/check the error messages.

Comment: DBI connect('server=<sid>;charset=iso_1;tdsLevel=CS_TDS_50','user',...) failed: Server message number=4002 severity=14 state=1 line=0 server=sid text=Login failed.
 OpenClient message: LAYER = (4) ORIGIN = (1) SEVERITY = (4) NUMBER = (44) by the way the result is the same when I mix up the order of the databases to connect to @dgw

Comment: Well, now that you found the culprit ... try to find out why you cannot connect to that specific server. It is no problem of the perl script (anymore).

Comment: @dgw I think it is, because when I put this specific server that raised the error in the beginning of the array, it connects just fine. It does not matter in which order I connect to the databses. It is always the 5th one that cannot be connected.

Comment: Tip: Don't make your variables "global" like that! The whole point of declaring them is to limit their scope to where they are needed, a process you subverted by placing all the declarations at the top!

Comment: When I declare them inside the loop, is their scope limited to one iteration of the loop? I thought the scope would be for the remainder of the loop and therefore it is better to make them global.... @ikegami

Comment: Re "*When I declare them inside the loop, is their scope limited to one iteration of the loop?*", Exactly. This is *desirable*. Right now, you are reusing variables and letting them leak out of the loop where they are used. You should have `for my $sid (@sids) { my $dsn = '...'; my $dbh = ...; ... }`

Comment: `finish` [rarely needs to be called](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#finish), and it seems that both SQL queries could be combined into one.  Also, prepare/execute/fetchrow/done is common enough that the DBI provides a [convenience method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectrow_array) on the handle object:  `my ($sz, $ver) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT SUM(size), @@version ...')`

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be written as sample below (please see `if ... else ...` block for `$dbh`)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DBI;

my($user, $passwd)  = qw/someuser somepassword/;
my @sids            = qw/server1 server2 ... server#/;

foreach my $sid (@sids) {
        my $dsn = "dbi:Sybase:server=$sid;charset=iso_1;tdsLevel=CS_TDS_50";

        say "DSN: $dsn";

        my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd, {  PrintError => 1,
                                                        RaiseError => 1,
                                                        AutoCommit => 1,
                                                        syb_enable_utf8 => 1
                                                    }
                                );

        if( not defined ($dbh) ) {
            say "WARNING: Could not connect to $dsn";
        } else {
            say "INFO: DB connection established";

            my($size,$version);

            my $query = 'SELECT
                            SUM(size)
                         FROM 
                            master..sysusages
                        WHERE 
                            dbid = 4
                          AND 
                            segmap = 3
                        ';
            my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $sth->execute;

            while (@row = $sth->fetchrow) {
                    $size = $row[0];
            }

            $sth->finish;

            $query  = 'select @@version';
            $sth    = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $sth->execute;

            while (@row = $sth->fetchrow) {
                    $version = $row[0];
            }

            $sth->finish;

            $dbh->disconnect;

            $size = $size * 16 / 1024;
            say "SID: $sid, SIZE: $size, VERSION: $version";
        }
}
```

**NOTE:** `use strict; use warnings;` helps to avoid many pitfalls, `use diagnostics;` helps to identify a problem in difficult cases

**NOTE:** `$sth->fetchrow_hashref` allows address hash element by name, no need to count index of array as in case `$sth->fetch_rowarray`

Comment: Thank you for this input. I figure this is a good way skip the connects that are not working but the script crashes because of the failed dbi connect anyway

Comment: @laghorn -- at least in this case you get informed which database you can not connect to. Then investigate what could be a potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my naiv thinking I hid some lines of code that I was convinced could not be the reason for this misbehaviour. As it turns out, it was. So the reason for my problem was a simple logical error, that caused the password, that was used after a connect to a certain DB to be wrong.